# Cannot run powershell script from cmd.exe?

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-2.0, cmd

I wrote a powershell script that can be run from powershell like so:

```
PS C:> S:\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"
```

I've stored it on a shared drive (S:), and I cannot run my powershell script in this form from either powershell or cmd.exe:

```
PS C:> powershell S:\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"
C:\> powershell S:\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"
```

I've also tried to run it bypassing the executionpolicy:

```
C:\> powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command S:\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"
```

I've also tried to run it with the full UNC path (in all the forms above):

```
C:\> powershell \\MyServer\path\to\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"
```

The only form that shows output is if I use a parameter that doesn't require a string to be passed:

```
C:\> powershell S:\MyScript.ps1 -z

thing
-----
thing1
thing2
thing3
```

Does anyone know why this is? Is there some way I can pass a string to the script from cmd.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also note, that powershell.exe has a parameter `-File` which might be better for a file than `-command`. I'm not sure about the script parameters as they should be grouped in a string like Nick said. Just try Nicks solution and if that doesn't work, try the `-File` parameter instead of `-command`.

Answer (score 2):

Try running it like this:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command {S:\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"}
```

All cmd knows is that you sent it the command `S:\MyScript.ps1` it doesn't know what to do with `-a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"`  by enclosing in `{ }` it should take the whole thing as the command to run.  If it still causes a problem then try this:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command " &{S:\MyScript.ps1 -a "select thing from table where name like 'name'"}"
```

Comment: Also note, that powershell.exe has a parameter `-File` which might be better for a file than `-command`. I'm not sure about the script parameters as they should be grouped in a string like Nick said. Just try Nicks solution and if that doesn't work, try the `-File` parameter instead of `-command`.

Comment: I've copied my comment as answer. Did a simple replace of `-command` through `-File` work or did you have to escape your parameters in some way?